# Change type and stereotype when drag Class element

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have my MDG extension which consists of custom diagram and custom element. If I drag standard Class element onto my diagram as a Property, there will be new element type of Property.

How to change this behavior ? I need to change, the type and stereotype on the fly when dragging a class on a diagram. The _instanceMode,  _instanceOwner , _instanceType  aren't applicable for standard Classes , only for MDG extension.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're after. _How to change this behavior ?_ to what?

Comment: If I drag Class element to Diagram it places as Class (via Link) or Part (via Property). It is a basic behavior of Sparx. I need a change behavior to following case : When I drag Class element to Diagram it change type of element from Class to another type, defined in my MDG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create an instance you need to define it in your profile as extension to Object and/or Property (depending on what you need). This profile element can be dragged from either a self-defined toolbox (preferrably connected to a diagram) or from the Profiles in the Resources window (if you don't have a full-fledged MDG and use the Resources to import your profile). Once you have created it you can link it via Ctrl-L to a classifier of your choice.